# Two google drive icons appear in taskbar

Tags: windows-10, google-drive

I've installed google drive only once on my laptop, but recently I always see two google drive icons in the taskbar. How can I solve it?
[image: google drive icons]

Comment: Right click and unpin one of them?

Comment: @DavidPostill when I right click on one of them just a small window comes which asks me to sign in.